# Jasmine unit test timing out - ReferenceError: jasmineRequire is not defined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, jasmine, resharper

I have few jasmine unit test that are run by Resharper 2016.3, but suddenly all tests are "Ignored : Task skipped on timeout".

I cannot figure out what is causing this behaviour.  All I know so far that for some reason Resharper test runner cannot find definition for "jasmineRequire.html = function(j$) {..." jasmineRequire, and it looks like this file is wrapped inside Resharper somewhere.

Can somebody help?

**EDIT**

I ran a comparison test, same code with R# 2016.2.1, jasmine version 2.4 and all jasmine unit tests passed. But R# 2016.3 with any version of jasmine give the error above.

Comment: You should file a bugreport. The manufacturer can help much better with this error. The error means that `jasmine.js` is not included before `jasmine-html.js` was included.

Comment: Thanks, I have raised an issue with Resharper.

Answer (score 1):

I raised this issue with Resharper and the solution is provided as follows

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462494

Rename any custom files that contains name "Jasmine-Something.js" to "JasmineSomething.js".